# Text tool menu obstructed when used at top of image

Tags: gimp

When I need to add text to the very top of an image, the text tool menu is obstructed by the top of the window. How can I get the entire menu into view?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the little compass icon at the bottom right of the image window to pan the canvas down and make the dialog show up:

[image]

For completeness:

The dialog is pinned to the canvas, so you have to move the canvas in the window, which is a "pan" operation. The usual spacebar+mouse-drag  won't work since the text tool is reading the keyboard, so you have to use the other way to pan. The usefulness of the navigation window is too often overlooked...

Comment: That works perfectly. Very obscure solution. I'll note that my version of Gimp (2.10.8) has an up arrow in case anyone else is confused at first.

Comment: See enhanced answer that lights a small candle in the obscurity. :)